# foreign key wouldn't create

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

foreign key wouldn't create even I did the right syntax,

```
ALTER TABLE nametable
ADD FOREIGN KEY (attribute) REFERENCES other_table(attribute);
```

also

```
ALTER TABLE nametable
ADD constraint FOREIGN KEY (attribute) REFERENCES other_table(attribute);
```

the problem's created just a key when I insert a number that not exists in the mother table its accept it

Comment: The alter table syntax looks fine. We need to see the table definitions for nametable and other_table.

Comment: CREATE table COUNTRY(
    IDcountry int(3) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY key,
    nom varchar(30)
    );

Comment: CREATE table REALISATEUR(
    IDrealisateur int(3) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY key,
    nom varchar(30),
    prenom varchar(30),
    age int(3),
    genre varchar(1),
    pays int(3) 
    );

Comment: alter table realisateur add CONSTRAINT fkp_idc
 FOREIGN key(pays) REFERENCES country(IDcountry);

Comment: You should include the engine in your table definitions. (BTW the code provided is fine if the engine is the same for both tables) see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7ad5b

Comment: yes i change the engine to inoodb ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

what system are you using?
If its Redshift, it doesnt enforce the constraint

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Dont have the right to comment yet, but i agree. Thanks P.Salmon